# Как заполнить столбцы, по значениям которые указаны в list в другом столбце DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть набор данных, в котором в столбце `period` указаны периоды (отрезки времени) в который включены даты `target_start` и `target_end`. Данные в каждой ячейке представлены в виде списка (но могут быть array и.т.д)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем в dataframe добавляются столбцы, которые соответствуют периодам и заполняются `np.nan`

```
date_min = df.target_start_date.min()
date_max = df.target_end_date.max()
period = pd.period_range(date_min, date_max, freq='M')

for i in period:
    df[str(i)] = np.nan
```

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне заменить значения `Nan` на `True`, если в соответствующем списке в столбце period есть такое значение?

Хочу получить такой результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# setup test data
data = {'period': [['2019-04'], ['2019-01'], ['2019-03'], ['2019-06', '2019-05']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# create periods
date_min = df.period.min()[0]
date_max = df.period.max()[0]

periods = pd.period_range(date_min, date_max, freq='M')

for i in periods:
    df[str(i)] = np.nan
```

output

```
    period              2019-01 2019-02 2019-03 2019-04 2019-05 2019-06
0   [2019-04]           NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   [2019-01]           NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   [2019-03]           NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   [2019-06, 2019-05]  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Как вы себе представляете попытку воспроизвести ваш код, если все исходные данные у вас в виде скриншотов?

Comment: добавил код для примера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы вам сразу не заполнять фрейм так, как вам нужно?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'period': [['2019-04'], ['2019-01'], ['2019-03'], ['2019-06', '2019-05']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

date_min = df.period.min()[0]
date_max = df.period.max()[0]

periods = pd.period_range(date_min, date_max, freq='M')

for i in periods:    
    df[str(i)] = np.where((df['period'].map(lambda x: str(i) in x)), True, False)
```

Получим:

```
               period  2019-01  2019-02  2019-03  2019-04  2019-05  2019-06
0           [2019-04]    False    False    False     True    False    False
1           [2019-01]     True    False    False    False    False    False
2           [2019-03]    False    False     True    False    False    False
3  [2019-06, 2019-05]    False    False    False    False     True     True
```

Обратите внимание на типы данных: если в строке `df[str(i)] = np.where((df['period'].map(lambda x: str(i) in x)), True, False)` вместо `False` вы используете `np.nan`, то значения True будут в датафрейме храниться как `1.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)


res = (pd.SparseDataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['period']).astype(bool), 
                          index=df.index, columns=mlb.classes_,
                          default_fill_value=False)
         .join(df))
```

результат:

```
In [15]: res
Out[15]:
   2019-01  2019-03  2019-04  2019-05  2019-06              period
0    False    False     True    False    False           [2019-04]
1     True    False    False    False    False           [2019-01]
2    False     True    False    False    False           [2019-03]
3    False    False    False     True     True  [2019-06, 2019-05]
```